# Find the image of a circle under $w = f(z) = 1/z$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

In my introductory complex analysis class, we've gone over a fair number of examples using the reciprocal function to map a line to a circle. However, we've worked only one example that used a circle as its domain, and my professor left a good portion of the problem undone. To top things off, my book focuses on, wouldn't you know, domains consisting of a line.

In this problem, the domain of $f$ is $C_{1/2}(-i/2) = \{z : |z+i/2| = 1/2\}$. Here's how I attempted to sort through it all:

$$\begin{eqnarray}x^2 + (y + i/2)^2 &=& \frac{1}{4} \\
\left(\frac{u}{u^2+v^2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{i}{2} - \frac{v}{u^2+v^2} \right)^2 &=& \frac{1}{4} \\
u^2 + \left[(i/2)(u^2+v^2)-v\right]^2 &=& \frac{1}{4}(u^2+v^2)^2 \\
u^2+v^2-vi(u^2 + v^2) - \frac{1}{4}(u^2+v^2)^2 &=& \frac{1}{4}(u^2+v^2)^2 \\
(1-vi)(u^2+v^2) &=& \frac{1}{2}(u^2+v^2)^2 \\
1-vi &=& \frac{1}{2}(u^2+v^2) \\
2 &=& u^2 + v^2 + 2vi \\
1 &=& u^2 + (v+i)^2
\end{eqnarray}$$

And so the image is itself a circle, centered at $(0,-1)$, with radius $1$.

Does this look okay? Have I been sloppy with any of the notation?  I feel like I'm still figuring a lot of this out, so please nitpick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to do this.  As usual, the more theory you know, the less hard work you have to do.  Here are **hints** for a lo-tech method, followed by a hi-tech method.

First a **comment**.  The method you are attempting is to write a complex variable as two real variables.  This being the case,
$$x^2+\Bigl(y+\frac{i}{2}\Bigr)^2=\frac{1}{4}$$
*cannot possibly be right*, since it is supposed to be a real equation yet it includes $i$.  It should be
$$x^2+\Bigl(y+\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)^2=\frac{1}{4}\ .$$
If you make this change and then do more or less what you already tried (but there is also some careless algebra which you will have to fix) it should work.

For the "hi-tech/lo-algebra" method you will have to know the following theorem: the image of a circle through the origin under the map $w=1/z$ is a line.  So, take two points on your circle, say
$$z=-i\quad\hbox{and}\quad z=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i\ .$$
(Not $z=0$ as then $w=\infty$, or to put it in finite terms, $w$ does not exist.)  Find $w$ for both of these and then determine the line through the two $w$ values.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, David. I started over without the complex numbers and ended up with $(1-v)(u^2+v^2)=0$. The latter of these factors can equal $0$ only when $u=v=0$, but that can't be, considering how $x$ and $y$ are defined. Therefore, $1-v=0$, which means $v=1$. That leaves us with a horizontal line, i.e., $\{w : \Im(w) = 1\}$.

Comment: Also: I tried checking my answer using your hi-tech method, but I had one question: Did you mean $z=-i$, rather than $z=-1$? Using $-i$ and the other value you pointed out, I found two elements of my set up above, but I want to make sure I'm doing everything correctly.

Comment: Yes, $z=-i$, I'll fix it.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If the domain consists of all points in the complex plane whose distance from $-i/2$ is $1/2$, then $z = 0$ is one such point:  $|0 - i/2| = 1/2$.  In such a case, inversion through the unit circle under the mapping $w = f(z) = 1/z$ gives the point at infinity, so your algebra cannot possibly be correct.  The image is necessarily a line; moreover, it is a horizontal line that passes through the intersection point(s) of the unit circle and the circle centered at $-i/2$ with radius $1/2$.

Comment: I noticed the $1/0$ thing the other day in class but had forgotten; thanks for reminding me. I had assumed that meant, e.g., if we go out far enough on the line (i.e., the domain), we could get as close as we want to $0$ on the circle. Another point of confusion was that my professor had said $w=1/z$ "maps lines to lines and circles to circles", which was pretty much negated by the first example, when a line got mapped to a circle. I gradually deduced than either mapped to either. (Correctly? We saw an example mapping a circle to a circle, but you write the image is "necessarily" a line.)

Comment: Beyond that, could you please comment on where I went awry in my algebra?  Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: On the Riemann sphere $\mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}$, a line is a circle.  It is a circle with infinite radius.  Your professor's statement erroneously implies a distinction where there is none:  it should simply read, "$w = 1/z$ maps circles to circles," *where 'circle' also includes lines.*

Comment: Regarding where you calculations went awry, refer to David's reply:  once you express the image of the mapping in $\mathbb R^2$, there should be no more complex numbers in your expression:  the circle should be $(x,y)$ such that $x^2 + (y + 1/2)^2 = 1/4$.

Answer (score 1):

The typical domain point is
$$z= -\frac{i}{2} +\frac{1}{2} e^{i\theta}$$
The image of this point is 
$$\frac{1}{-\frac{i}{2} +\frac{1}{2}e^{i\theta}}=\frac{2}{-i+e^{i\theta}}=\frac{2}{\cos\theta -i(1-\sin\theta)}\cdot\frac{\cos\theta +i(1-\sin\theta)}{\cos\theta +i(1-\sin\theta)}$$
This simplifies to
$$\frac{\cos\theta}{1-\sin\theta} + i$$
Verify that the real part of this expression ranges between $\pm\infty$ as $\theta$ moves through $[0,2\pi]$.

So $\boxed{\text{the image is the horizontal line through }i}$.

Comment: This looks a *lot* different from how we'd been doing these problems, so I admit, it took me a while to have a close look at it. I'd forgotten that that's often the precise reason I *do* like an explanation. So anyway, yeah, I like this; it makes a lot of sense. Thank you!