# Mobius tranformation as composition of functions

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation

I was recently attempting the question:

Express the Mobius tranformation $f(z) = (2z + 3)/(z − 4)$ as the composition of maps of the
form $z → az, z → z + b$ and $z → 1/z$.
 Hence show that f maps the circle $|z − 2i| = 2$ onto the circle
$|8z + (6 + 11i)| = 11$.

So for the first part, let $a(z)=z-4 \ , b(z)= 1/z , \ c(z) = 11z, \ d(z) = z+2 $

Then $dcba(z)=dcb(z-4)=dc(1/(z-4)) = d(11/(z-4)) = 2+ 11/(z-4)= \frac{2z+3}{z-4}=f(z) $

But I'm not sure how this relates to the second part. I thought maybe looking at the transformation of the circle with each of these simpler mappings separately but I'm not sure it works: after applying $a(z) $ to the circle, we translate it $-4$ in direction of +ve real axis so the image is $ |z-4-2i|=2 $. But then what about after applying $b(z) $ ?
I assume I have missed something obvious. 
Any hints/help is appreciated.

Comment: In fact, the image of a circle by $z\mapsto \frac 1z$ is a line (so finding the image of 2 points of the circle is sufficient). See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675899/find-the-image-of-a-circle-under-w-fz-1-z

Comment: @paf are you sure that thats true? Any mobius transformation maps circles to circles: Consider the circle $|z-a|=r$. Writing this as $(z-a)( \bar{z-a} )$ we get $z \bar{z} -a \bar{z} - \bar{a} z + a \bar{a} - r^{2}=0$. Applying z↦1/z and multiplying by $z \bar{z}$ we have $1-az- \bar{a} \bar{z} +(a \bar{a} - r^{2}) z \bar{z} =0 $. This is still in the form of a circle.